# La app se detiene al querer abrir otro activity

Tags: java, android

Al intentar abrir otra `activity` se detiene la *App*, tengo un `activity` con un `TabsHost` e intento abrir otro con un `TabHost`. Les dejo el código, espero me puedan ayudar:

El java del `MainActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TabHost tabs= (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.Tabs2);
    tabs.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabs.newTabSpec("Login");
    spec.setIndicator("Login");
    spec.setContent(R.id.Login);
    tabs.addTab(spec);

    spec=tabs.newTabSpec("registro");
    spec.setIndicator("Registrase");
    spec.setContent(R.id.Registrase);
    tabs.addTab(spec);

    tabs.setCurrentTab(0);
}

public void evtLogIn(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainPage.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

El `XML` de `Main`:

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/Tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:hint="Nombre de usuario"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:hint="Contraseña"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Ingresar"
                    android:onClick="evtLogIn"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Registrase"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:hint="Nombre de usuario"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:hint="Contraseña"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:hint="Confirmar contraseña"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Registrarse"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

el otro `XML` es prácticamente lo mismo y el java de ese `Activity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);

    TabHost tabs= (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.Tabs);
    tabs.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabs.newTabSpec("Publicaciones");
    spec.setIndicator("Publicaciones");
    spec.setContent(R.id.Publicaciones);
    tabs.addTab(spec);

    spec=tabs.newTabSpec("Publica");
    spec.setIndicator("Publica");
    spec.setContent(R.id.Publicar);
    tabs.addTab(spec);

    tabs.setCurrentTab(0);
}
```

Comment: Qué error muestra?  en el "log"

Comment: me es imposible saberlo, android studio no me reconoce ni el celular en modo debug ni el emulador que tengo instalado

Comment: podrías empezar por obtener los logs. Intenta resolver el problema del IDE o usa adb por linea de comandos https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html?hl=es-419

Comment: ¿Has declarado MainPage en tu manifest? Pero como dicen, colocar el Logcat seria de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He reproducido tu código y te comento lo que pueden ser tus problemas, ya que comentas que no puedes ver el `Logcat`.

**1**. Mira en tu `AndroidManifest` si has declarado ambas `clases`, deberías tener algo así:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainPage"></activity>
```

**2**. En tu clase `MainActivity` declaras como *id*

```
TabHost tabs= (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.Tabs2);
```

pero en tu `main` lo declaras como `Tabs`. Muy importante eso, comprueba que tienes la misma **id** en la clase como `layout`.

**3**. Te dejo un ejemplo de como deberías tener`MainPage` y `activity_main_page`, qué es donde comentas que se te cierra.

`MainPage`:

```
public class MainPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);

        TabHost tabs = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.Tabs2);
        tabs.setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabs.newTabSpec("Publicaciones");
        spec.setIndicator("Publicaciones");
        spec.setContent(R.id.Publicaciones);
        tabs.addTab(spec);

        spec = tabs.newTabSpec("Publica");
        spec.setIndicator("Publica");
        spec.setContent(R.id.Publicar);
        tabs.addTab(spec);

        tabs.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

`activity_main_page`

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/Tabs2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Publicaciones"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hola"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Publicar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: Me has salvado hermano muchas gracias :D